# How to set enter button onserverclick?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="autosuggest span10 classic-search" autofocus="true" tabindex="1" />
    <button class="btn" type="button" id="SchButton" onserverclick="GetDistributorRegNo" runat="server">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

I want to search content on press enter key. But i have onserverclick there is not work by jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your inputs and buttons in a form tag like this:

```
 <form id="form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="autosuggest span10 classic-search" autofocus="true" tabindex="1" />
       <button class="btn" type="submit" id="SchButton" onserverclick="GetDistributorRegNo" runat="server">
        <i class="icon-search"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now when you press enter it will call `onserverclick="GetDistributorRegNo"` and send the form data to the server.

Edit: Your code behind should look something like this to receive the form data

```
 protected void Page_Load(Object Source, EventArgs E)   
  {   
    if (IsPostBack)   
    {   
      // Process Form data here...   
    }       
  }
```

Comment: change your button type to submit and try again

Comment: Can you try to send Code behind. i will also try to use type button or etc etc...

Comment: I updated my question to show how to capture form data in the code behind. make sure in the html your button is type="submit" and everything should work